I can't apply texture to object imported from Sketchup
I imported a file from Sketchup into Blender using the Sketchup Importer extension. Now when I try to put a texture on the mesh it changes color to solid, but the texture does not show up.
The picture shows the top mesh with the texture I created in Blender, and on the right is the brown mesh from the imported model with the same texture applied.
I would be grateful for advice.

